# Image in button isn't scaled to the size of the button (WIN32 API)

Tags: c, winapi, button, common-controls

So I was trying to make an image button using the WIN32 API.
The problem is, that the image gets cropped, because the button is smaller than the image.
In a statics control, I would user the `SS_REALSIZECONTROL` tag, but in a button that doesn't seem to work.

Here is how I created the button:

```
hButton = CreateWindowA("Button", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_BITMAP, 10, 10, 70, 70, hWindow, BUTTON_ID, NULL, NULL);
```

And here is how I set its image:

```
SendMessageA(hButton, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, hBitmap);
```

Comment: You can either make your button bigger or make the image smaller. Neither will happen automatically.

Comment: Or use a custom draw button. Draw the image scaled to fit the destination rectangle. Refer to "[About cropping and scaling GDI+ images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-cropping-and-scaling-images-about)" and "[Scaling an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/scaling-an-image)".

Comment: That's too bad, but I thought that this will be the answer. Thanks!